# what is the type of decltype(function) and why I do not need "const" qualifier here?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-specialization, explicit-specialization

I am confused of the type of `decltype` a function. It is neither a function pointer nor functor. How can I use it? And why the full template specialization here does not require `const` qualifier.

```cpp
class SomeClass
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    void insideTemplateMethod(const T & value)
    {
    }
};
template
void SomeClass::insideTemplateMethod<decltype(std::hex)>(decltype(std::hex) & ); // no need to specify const

template
void SomeClass::insideTemplateMethod<int>(int &); // error, must specify const

int main(void)
{}
```

if I remove the `&`, it then complains that

```sh
error: template-id 'insideTemplateMethod<std::ios_base&(std::ios_base&)>' for 'void SomeClass::insideTemplateMethod(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&))' does not match any template declaration"
```

Look, the `decltype(std::hex)` in parameter field is deducted to `std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)`, whereas it is deducted to `std::ios_base&(std::ios_base&)` in the parameter of template.

Could you please help me understand it?

Comment: Functions are immutable and so const to function pointer is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

`std::hex` is a function, with the following declaration (see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex)):

```
std::ios_base& hex( std::ios_base& str );
```

If `T` is the type of this function, namely `std::ios_base&(std::ios_base&)`, then because it is a function type, `const T` is the same as `T`. This is why the explicit instantiation definition can be written without the `const`.

Note that if you remove the `&` from the explicit instantiation definition, then the function parameter type `decltype(std::hex)` undergoes the standard transformation from a function type to a function pointer type. This is why you are seeing `(*)` in the error message.

Comment: Just to clarify for the OP: Without the &, the function type "decays". That is a standard process from C++ where arrays decay to pointers and functions to function pointers.

Answer (score 0):

To cite [the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#7):

> The effect of a *cv-qualifier-seq* in a function declarator is not the same as adding *cv-qualification* on top of the function type. In the latter case, the *cv-qualifiers* are ignored. [ Note: A function type that has a *cv-qualifier-seq* is not a *cv-qualified* type; there are no *cv-qualified* function types. — end note ]
>   [ Example:
>
> ```
> typedef void F();
> struct S {
>     const F f;        // OK: equivalent to: void f();
> };
> ```
>
> — end example
>    ]